# Regex range from 1-24 with optional fractional part

Tags: regex, range

I need a regex which allow value from 1 - 24.

I have tried with the below one and its taking values till `29`. Can anyone help with the correct regex format for this one?

```
^([1-9](\.\d+)?|[12]\d|2[0-4](\.0+)?)$
```

Comment: `[12]\d` matches `29` as `\d` = `[0-9]`

Comment: But if i remove the same then it wont accept from 11-19.

Comment: Remove just `2`, try [`^(?:(?:2[0-3]|1\d|[1-9])(?:\.\d+)?|24(?:\.0+)?)$`](https://regex101.com/r/kLFn2O/2).

Comment: This is definitely **not** a job for `regex`. It can be done but there are better ways. For example, write a `regex` that matches 1 and 2 digit numbers and an optional fraction part (`\b\d\d?(\.\d*)?\b` or `\b\d{1,2}(\.\d*)?\b`), use it to identify the numbers in the input string then use the numbers comparison operator provided by the language you use to verify that the numbers found are smaller than or equal to `29`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your pattern, `[12]\d` matches `29` as `\d` can match any digit, `0` to `9`. Besides, `[12]\d` alternative does not allow matching fractional part, and `2[0-4](\.0+)?` will only allow `0` fractional part for numbers from `20` to `23` (only zeros are expected for `24` value).

Use

```
^(?:(?:2[0-3]|1\d|[1-9])(?:\.\d+)?|24(?:\.0+)?)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kLFn2O/2/)

**Pattern details**

- `^`- start of string
- `(?:` - a non-capturing group to hold 2 alternatives:

  - `(?:2[0-3]|1\d|[1-9])(?:\.\d+)?` - either `20`, `21`, `22`, `23` (matched with `2[0-3]`) or `10` to `19` (matched with `1\d`) or a `1` to `9` (`[1-9]`) that are optionally followed with `.` and any 1+ digits (fractional part)
  - `|` - or
  - `24(?:\.0+)?` - `24` optionally followed with `.` and one or more zeros
- `)` - end of the non-capturing group
- `$`  - end of string.